# vbo holds only same size vertex?

Tags: iphone, opengl-es, vbo

Does OpenGL/OpenGLES VBO hold only same size vertex?

I'm asking because i found that the parameters for glDrawElements have offset value for index buffer only (its last parameter), this means : 
  1. i have to manually offset my indices before submit them to IBO if buffers already been partly filled. anyway, manually offset indices is easy, so its not a problem here.
  2. the VBO being used as vertex buffer must holds same size vertices or the indices are meaningless.

This behavior is different from DirectX Vertex Buffer, in directx, there is a SetStreamSource, which can be used to offset Verterx Buffer, along with DrawIndexedPrimitive your VB can hold vertices in arbitrary size.

maybe OpenGLES 1.1 version of SetStreamSource is not available? maybe OpenGLES 2.0 will support it?

My Target platform is iPhone OpenGLES 1.1, so if the GL version SetStreamSource is not available im going to give up using VBOs because :
  1. it brings more trouble (i'll have to allocate many VBOs holding different size vertex)
  2. there is no performance improvement anyway (no hardware support in OpenGLES 1.1)

thanks for reading and thanks a lot for sharing your experience about correct ways to use VBOs in OpenGLES 1.1., thank you.

Comment: What do you understand by "same size vertex"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OpenGL buffer objects (VBO is one of the usage patterns) can contain arbitrary information. But the draw functions (like `glDrawElements`) work on a continuous array of same-formatted vertex information (obviously, each vertex occupies the same size). If that's the size you were asking about - then I don't see how it can be altered.

If you want to use the VBO from the specific offset (for example, containing vertices of a different format) - then there is a last parameter of `glVertexAttribPointer` for you. When VBO is bound, this last parameter is a byte offset of the data segment used for vertex attributes.

Comment: thanks kvark, i've known how to solve my problem as soon as i saw your 'glVertexAttribPointer', its very enlightening (actually it should be 'glVertexPointer' in my case), i've used that function many times, unfortunately i totally forgot it while i was looking at 'glDrawElements' at a loss. thank you.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure I fully understand what you mean when you say that you have different sizes of vertices. But OpenGL can handle whatever vertex formats D3D can.

What OpenGL does not have is the concept of vertex "streams." That is because it does not need them; think of each individual attribute (positions, normals, colors, etc) as a separate stream. But they can all come from the same buffer and they can all be interwoven with each other.

The way buffer objects work is quite simple. A buffer object is just a sized block of memory controlled by OpenGL. You can put whatever bytes in it that you want.

To tell OpenGL how to fetch vertex data from it, you must define a number of arrays, each associated with an attribute. The functions for this are glVertexPointer, glNormalPointer, etc; they are all of the form gl*Pointer. That much you seem to already grasp.

What you may not understand is that the vertex format defined by these functions is not permanently associated with the buffer object. For example, you can use 3D positions with byte colors, all from the same buffer object:

```
glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, bufferObject);
glEnableClientState(GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);   //Our vertices contain positions.
glVertexPointer(3, GL_FLOAT, 16, (void*)0);  //The last parameter is the byte offset from the beginning of the buffer to where the data starts.
glEnableClientState(GL_COLOR_ARRAY);    //Our vertices contain colors.
glColorPointer(4, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, 16, (void*)12); //Offset must add in the 3 floats from the vertex.
//Draw stuff.
```

Then later, you can redefine this pointer, changing the format however you want. This time, we use 2D positions, defined as shorts, and no colors at all:

```
glEnableClientState(GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);
glVertexPointer(2, GL_SHORT, 4, (void*)1024);
glDisableClientState(GL_COLOR_ARRAY);  //Our vertices contain no colors.
//Draw stuff.
```

The buffer binding was not changed between these calls. This new array starts 1024 bytes from the beginning of the buffer. So you can put the data for multiple objects in the same buffer.

Now, there is one thing OpenGL ES 1.1 does not offer that D3D does. When you call DrawIndexedPrimitives, you can supply an offset that is added to each index before fetching vertices from the arrays. Desktop OpenGL 3.2 and above provides this (and lower versions via extensions), but not ES 1.1.

Comment: I assume the magic numbers are just for illustration purposes?  Real code should use `sizeof` and `offsetof`.

Comment: Thanks Nicol Bolas and the detailed explaination. you are correct about "The way buffer objects work is quite simple" :P. I've solved my problem using glVertexPointer, dont know why i totally fogot it when i post my question, my bad. thank you again and have a nice day.